# Arithmetic progression sum equation

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic

I have faced an equation that I just cannot solve. I know that it must be solved using geometric progression sum forumla, but I don't know how to find the difference.  Maybe you could help me? :)
$$ \dfrac{1}{x+x^2+\cdots} = \dfrac{7}{2}$$, if 
$$0< x < 1$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: $x+x^2+\cdots = x(1+x+\cdots) = \dfrac{x}{1-x} = \dfrac{2}{7}$